# Pick up a number in a two dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I try to understand how arrays work with this simple code. (this is for homework)

First you are supposed to choose a row (there is only 2)

Then you pick a column (there are 4)

The part I have a problem with is if the user chooses a unauthorised row eller column.

The idea is that you choose a row and then a column; after that the program writes out what was in that array-box.

I assume that what I do wrong is the curly brackets but I really don't know how to proceed.

I should add that my main is in another file but I guess it does not matter.

```
#include "array4.h"

/*That's the content of array4.h
#ifndef ARRAYS_ARRAY4_H
#define ARRAYS_ARRAY4_H

const int rowMAX=1;
const int columnMAX=3;

int array4();

#endif //ARRAYS_ARRAY4_H*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int array4() {
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    int twodim[2][4] = {{3, 9, 7, 1},
                        {6, 2, 8, 5}};

    cout << "Choose row 0 or 1: ";

    if (row <= rowMAX)
        cin >> row;
    else if (row > rowMAX)
        cout << "Chose a lower row number: " << rowMAX;
    cin >> row;

    cout << "Chose column 0 to 3: ";

    if (column <= columnMAX)
        cin >> column;
    else if (column > columnMAX)
        cout << "Chose a lower column number: " << columnMAX;
    cin >> column;

    cout << twodim[row][column];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your issue? Does the program not work?

Comment: You seem to be asking for the row and column twice since you don't use {} to create a scope on your else if statements. With that said, you probably want a loop and reprompt if the number entered is outside the range. What if they entered 10 the second time?

Comment: @drescherjm no, it does not work, I have to enter both row and column twice!

Comment: Why do people voted down this question? I thought it was ok to ask even though you were beginner?

Comment: Beginner, yes.  That's fine.  But you still have to show your effort, where you're stuck, and what you're trying to do.  Being a beginner doesn't give you a free pass to expect us to do it all for you.

Comment: Probably because you did not explain very well what was your problem and how your program was not operating the way you expected. Remember the voting is based on how useful this question can help future readers with the same problem. If you don't describe your problem well it does not make a good question to help or teach future readers. With that said I did not downvote.

Comment: @fbueckert what do you mean, I wrote the code and I wrote exactly what the problem was ? Did you read? ''The part I have a problem with is if the user chooses a unauthorised row eller column.''

Comment: ***I wrote the code and I wrote exactly what the problem was ?*** Again, you did not explain your problem very well. The following is not a good explanation of your problem: ***The part I have a problem with is if the user chooses a unauthorised row eller column.***  Why is this code a problem? What happens? You leave it up to the readers to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be much better used with `while` loops in order to get a row and column continuously until you get a good one!

```
int array4() {
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    int twodim[2][4] = {{3, 9, 7, 1},
                        {6, 2, 8, 5}};

    //get row
    cout << "Choose row 0 or 1: ";
    cin >> row;
    while (row < 0 || row > rowMAX){
         cout << "invalid row!" << endl;
         cin >> row;
    }

    //get column
    cout << "Choose col 0 to 3: ";
    cin >> column;
    while (column < 0 || column > columnMAX){
         cout << "invalid column!" << endl;
         cin >> column;
    }

    cout << twodim[row][column];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use of `if-else` is not appropriate when you want to make sure that the user enters valid input. A `while` loop is better for that.

```
cout << "Choose row 0 or 1: ";
while ( cin >> row ) // Mae sure that input was read successfully.
{
   if ( row < 0 || row > rowMAX )
   {
      cout << row << " is an invalid value for row. Choose 0 or 1: "
   }
   else
   {
      // Got valid input. Break out of the loop.
      break;
   }
}
```

Update the code similarly to receive `col` from the user.